# move_uploaded_file() returns false when trying to upload an image

Tags: php, file, file-upload, image-uploading

So i'm passing an array of files that come from a type="file" input, and I want to send them to a folder on the server. The move_uploaded_file() is not working.

I just want to get one file to upload first, and will make loop or something for the whole array after.

I do have enctype="multipart/form-data" in the html form. The path is correct and that folder is empty.

Tried to set $image_paths[0] = $images[0]["tmp_name"] right before the inner if inside the first if and it retuns "/tmp/php2SytkN". Is that what tmp_name looks like? Also tried to return $images[0]['size'] and it's correct, so the file is there.

```
function upload_to_file($images){

$image_paths = array();
$target_dir = "uploads/images/";
$path = $target_dir . basename($images[0]["name"]);
if(isset($images[0]) && $images[0]['size'] > 0) {

    if (move_uploaded_file($images[0]["tmp_name"], $path)) {
        $image_paths[0] = $path;
    }
}
return $image_paths;

}
```

EDIT: I tried it but I don't think $_FILES[0] would work since I'm already using that. I'd also need a second $_FILES array to also store videos, so I wanted to make my own arrays.

Her's what im trying to do im more detail:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//main form is submitted

    // upload each of the selected images into a directory on the server and return the array of paths for each one:
    $image_paths = upload_to_file($_SESSION['images']);
    //then insert those paths as varchar in a database table and return the id of the new table row:
    $images_fk = upload_to_db($image_paths);
    //finally insert the the id of the umages row into the main table along with all the other form stuff:
    $query = "INSERT INTO main_table (...other stuff from the main form..., images_fk) VALUES (...other stuff from the main form...'{$images_fk}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

}elseif(isset($_POST['submit_image'])){//image form is submitted

     if(count($_SESSION['images']) < 5){
          //store the file into a session array so a new image can be selected with the same input type=file:
          array_push($_SESSION['images'], $_FILES['image_file']);
     }

}
```

EDIT: HTML part:

```
//a form with one type=file input that submits to the top of the page:
<form id="form" action="home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="8000000">

        <input class="upload_btn" type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file">

  //some mix of php and html to show the names of uploaded items as you select them:
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['images']); $i++) {
            if($_SESSION['images'][$i] != null){
                echo "<p>";
                echo htmlentities($_SESSION['images'][$i]['name']) . "&nbsp&nbsp";
                echo "<a href='image_remove.php?ind=" . urlencode($i) . "'>Remove</a></p>";
            }
        } ?>
        <input type="submit" id="img_submit" class="form_button" name="submit_image" value="upload"/>
    </form>

    //Then do the same form for videos....
```

Comment: Superglobal array available everywhere. so use $_FILES  and $images also not bad